# C# - Adding specific type to generic

Tags: c#, generics

Im want to make method more user comfortable in method with Generic T

```
public class foo_Class
    {
        public My_Class(object ob, string foo)
        {
            this.ob = ob;
            this.foo = foo;
        }
        public object ob { get; set; }
        public string foo { get; set; }
    }
```

so when im adding foo_Class to Dictionary for example,
we have to write like this.

```
Dictionary<string, foo_Class> foo_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, foo_Class>();

foo_Dictionary.Add("foo", new foo_Class(Value1, "fo"));
```

but i just want to write like this using override,

```
Dictionary<string, My_class> My_Dictionary = new Dictionary<string, My_class>();

My_Dictionary.Add("foo", Value1, "fo");
...
```

So, help me to solve this prob.

Thx.

Comment: I really wish I understood what you're asking. Can you please read [ask] and [mcve] and then, based on what you've read, edit your question to make it clearer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to extend `Dictionary<string, MyClass>`:

```
// some names are renamed to follow C# conventions
public class MyDictionary : Dictionary<string, MyClass> {
    public void Add(string key, object value, MyEnum flags) {
        Add(key, new MyClass(value, flags));
    }
}
```

Then you would be able to do:

```
var dict = new MyDictionary();
dict.Add("myClass1", myValue1, MyEnum.Enum1);
dict.Add("myClass2", myValue2, MyEnum.Enum2);
```

If you only plan on adding methods to `Dictionary<string, MyClass>`, an [extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods) is a better choice.

```
public static class MyClassDictionaryExtensions {
    public static void Add(
        this Dictionary<string, MyClass> dict, 
        string key,  
        object value, 
        MyEnum flags) {
        dict.Add(key, new MyClass(value, flags));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, MyClass>();
dict.Add("myClass1", myValue1, MyEnum.Enum1);
dict.Add("myClass2", myValue2, MyEnum.Enum2);
```

Comment: wow. i didnt know about extension method. thx for new knowledge